# Launch a Uitableview controller from UIbar buttons created dynamically

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, launch

```
- (void)createBarButtons
{
    UIBarButtonItem *myCheckButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Check Records" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(checkRecordsAction)];
    UIBarButtonItem *mySaveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveAction)];
    [mySaveButton setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34.0/255.0 green:97.0/255.0 blue:221.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
    NSArray *myButtonArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:mySaveButton, myCheckButton,nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = myButtonArray;
}
```

I dont know if this question falls under too localized category. But help me out here.So like you see i have created two bar button items. Save is just saving the data onto CoreData,works just fine. But the check records should launch a new UITableviewcontroller.

```
- (void)checkRecordsAction
{
NSLog(@"the new stack action");
ITMSyncRecordsTVC *syncRecords  = [[ITMSyncRecordsTVC alloc]init];
//  [self presentViewController:syncRecords animated:YES completion:^{
//  self.navigationController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250);}];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:syncRecords animated:YES];
}
```

`ITMSyncRecordsTVC` is a `TableViewController` with a "Back" button on it.So when i click the check records it launches a `tableview` controller but no values in it and it does not show the "Back" bar button i put on it. Until now i have been using segues and storyboards just fine. But how do i launch a new view controller without them i dont know. My first leap into ios is ios6. I am missing something I dont know. So let me know how to call/launch a new TableViewController. In android we had intents that did the trick. Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks...
EDIT: So i edited my `checkRecordsAction` code.

EDIT :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
ITMOrdersVC *ordersVC = [[ITMOrdersVC alloc]init];
NSLog(@"at line 188 %d",indexPath.row);
if(indexPath.row < self.salesOrdersArray.count)
{
    ordersVC.salesOrder = [self.salesOrdersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"the sales purchase order number is %@",ordersVC.salesOrder.purchaseOrderNumber);

    NSLog(@"done - 140");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ordersVC animated:YES];
}
}
```

So on selecting a row on ITMSyncRecordsTVC table view controller it does the above. I get a new ITMOrdersVC screen with "Back" bar button at the left and 2 dynamically generated bar buttons.I get the 2 dynamically generated bar buttons but not the back. I thought once i click the row it will "go back" to previous screen to which i am passing the salesOrder object. My next step was to check if i get the salesorder object from the TVC then load it. So basically 2 screens only. First screen (save,check sync records). Second screen click a.) back(go to first screen..do nothing) or b.)click a row in second screen and populate first screen without the bar button.If it is not clear please ask me.

Comment: Do you have any delegates in `ITMSyncRecordsTVC`? Is it getting called? In order to see the normal back button, you need to do `pushViewController`.

Comment: @Rob. I edited the code to have init. I still don't see the Back button.

Comment: @Rob. Yes. I have embedded my ITMSyncRecordsTVC in a navigation controller. So there are 3 controllers on my storyboard 1.Screen which has all controls (including the dynamically generated 2 bar buttons) 2. Navigation Controller 3.ITMSyncRecordsTVC table view controller.

Comment: @Rob.Also its going in sort of loop.I click "Check Sync Records" and it shows up the ITMSyncRecordsTVC. I have "OrderedItems" as the back button now.I click that and it takes me back to the previous screen.If i click one of the rows in the ITMSyncRecordsTVC it launches a new Ordered Items form. I am adding some more code as to what i did.Please check it out.

Comment: @Rob. Ok i made that change. First VC is embedded in a Navigation Controller now and there is only the TVC..So three controllers again.

Comment: See my answer for the typical way to add a push segue to a storyboard and then to invoke that segue from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch a new table view controller using storyboards, you want to:

1. Have your main scene embedded in a navigation controller.

   [image: embed main scene in nav controller]
2. You want to have a push segue from the main controller to the second one. So control-drag from the view controller icon (in the bar below the main scene) to the next scene:

   [image: add push segue]
3. It should then look like (note the appearance of the navigation bar in the destination table view):

   [image: destination has navigation bar]
4. Then select the segue and give it a "storyboard identifier":

   [image: give segue storyboard id]
5. And now, your code to transition to that scene would look like:

The `checkRecordsAction`:

```
- (void)checkRecordsAction
{
    NSLog(@"the new stack action");

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushSegue" sender:self];
}
```

---

**Update:**

By the way, in the interest of full disclosure, there's an alternative to the push segue. If you give that next scene, itself, a "storyboard id", you can use the following code (obviously replacing `"insertNextScenesStoryboardIdHere"` with the identifier you give your next scene:

```
- (void)checkRecordsAction
{
    NSLog(@"the new stack action");

    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"insertNextScenesStoryboardIdHere"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I personally don't like this as much, as your storyboard now has a scene floating out there without any segue, your code now has dictated the nature of the transition between view controllers vs having everything in the storyboard, etc., but it is another approach.